# how to change laravel directory from storage/app/public to public/media

Tags: laravel-5

Please i want to change the default laravel configuration from storage/app/public to public/media on the server. In localhost it worked with storage:link but on the server it isn't working even after adding a symlink. Below is my symlink code.

```
<?php symlink('/home/cemo/cem/storage/app/public','/home/cemo/public_html');
```

Also if i return the public_path() from the store function i get /home/cemo/cem/public

[this is the structure of my cpanel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODDqD.png)

below is my store function using image intervention

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    return public_path();

    $this->validate($request,[
      'title'=>'required|min:6',
      'body'=>'required'
    ]);

        if($request->hasFile('image')){
            $img = $request->file('image');
            $imgName = time().'-'.uniqid() . '.' . $img->getClientOriginalExtension();
        }
        else{
            $imgName = 'default.jpg';
        }

    $posts = new post;

    $posts->title = $request->title;
    $posts->body = $request->body;
    $posts->posted_by = $request->posted_by;
    $posts->status = $request->status;
    $posts->position = $request->position;
    $posts->image = $imgName;
    $posts->source = $request->source;


    $posts->save();

    $posts->tags()->sync($request->tags);

    if(!empty($img)){
        Image::make($img)->resize(1500,550)->save(public_path('/media/images/blog/'. $imgName));
      }

     $notification = array(
         'message' => 'Successfully created',
         'alert-type' => 'success'
     );
     return redirect(route('post.index'))->with($notification);
}
```

Comment: Is `/home/cem` valid vs `/home/cemo`?

Comment: Could you use `mod_write` or the like instead?

Comment: @KamilG. i have edited it now

Comment: @fyroc that resulted in 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Shouldn't it be? `<?php symlink('/home/cemo/cem/storage/app/public','/home/cemo/public_html/media');`

Comment: @fyroc that doesn't work

Comment: @Polaris didn't work

Answer (score 0):

In config/filesystems.php

Change the array to:

```
'root' => 'public/media',
```